# access linux folder on virtualbox vm from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I am running Windows 10 version 1903 with VirtualBox 6.0.10, wth Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM. I am trying to access a folder in Ubuntu from Windows 10 and I have failed completely to find any up to date information on how to do this. All the information I can find is for outdated configurations.

Comment: Why don't [VirtualBox/SharedFolders](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders) work for you? Have you installed Guest Additions?

Comment: I have guest additions installed. I found the virtual box shared folders dialogue totally incomprehensible. I could not understand what data it wanted from me.

Comment: I checked the link you supplied and it is not helpful since it describes accessing a Windows share from Linux and I want to access a Linux share from Windows.

Comment: Another reason VIrtualBox/SharedFolders are not helpful is that they don't work well with soft links in Linus guests.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by implementing Samba in Ubuntu and connecting to the Samba shares from Windows. However, I had to overcome a Linux bug that is at least 10 years old and was reported to Fedora in 2009. The component `nmbd` in Ubuntu that actually publishes shares via Netbios was crashing and was unable to report the existence of the Samba shares. It was crashing, because it needed a working network before completing its' initialization. The reason for this situation was that Ubuntu was running in a VM and hence was taking longer than normal to initialize and the network was not yet available when `nmbd` tried to initialize itself. In addition, the VM had only been given one thread which slowed things down even more. My workaround was to increase the number of threads available to Ubuntu to 4. With this change, `nmbd` came up properly and all my problems disappeared.

This workaround was fine for my case but might not be sufficient in all cases. I considered, if necessary, modifying the `systemd` configuration files to make `nmbd` not start until network initialization was done. This is a more general workaround than the one I used and should work in many more situations, including with Ubuntu on a bare machine and not in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main methods in VirtualBox for sharing folders between host and guest:

- Create a SAMBA network share on the Linux machine.
  The Windows host will then be able to access it from the network.
- Use [shared folders](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders).

None of these options is easy, especially on the Linux side, since all cases
involve modifications to configuration files and entering commands in the console.
But there is no other way than acquiring the necessary Linux knowledge, and
many resources are available on the Web.
The Linux way of doing things is much different from Windows.

It is usually easier for a Windows host to share its folder, than doing the opposite.
If you are trying to share from the Linux guest to the host, SAMBA may be the
easier route.

Some references among the so many that exist:

- [Students Tutorial – View VirtualBox Host Shared Folders from Guest Machines](https://websiteforstudents.com/students-tutorial-view-virtualbox-host-folders-guest-machines/)
- [How To Set Up a Samba Share For A Small Organization on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-samba-share-for-a-small-organization-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I started off trying a Samba share but found no way to get Windows to recognize the Samba share.

Comment: This is most probably a permissions problem, and the simplest is to allow unlimited access to the SAMBA share. Research the question on google, try, and if you fail then ask here specific questions as regarding SAMBA including your configuration changes. As I said, host sharing is much easier.

Comment: Again, the tutorial you shared goes the opposite way to what I want. I want to share a Linux folder in a guest VM from a Windows host and the tutorial assumes that the host is Linux.

Comment: I added a SAMBA article for that (a random one from virtually thousands of the available articles).